# Could not locat Device support files : I am not able to run iOS 14 Apps with XCode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

My iOS testing device was recently updated to iOS version 14.

When I plugged this to my MacBook Air (I have 2017 Model) it complained I need some software to access the device, so I did installed it from the button the popup provided.

When I try to run my development apps in this device, now it complaints,

> Could not locate device support files. This iPhone 6s is running iOS
> 14.2 which may not be supported by this version of XCode . An updated version of XCode maybe found at app store or at developer.apple.com

My OS Version - macOS Catalina 10.15.2

XCode version - 11.2.1 (11B500)

I searched and got to know I need XCode 12 and above to work with iOS 14.

Well, I CAN'T UPDATE XCODE, or the OS.

I can't afford any XCode update or an OS update with this laptop at this moment. I build apps using 'Flutter'

So, how I can I run apps again on this iOS 14 device? Maybe factory reset? Losing data in mobile is not an issue as these are test devices. Or maybe device support files I can install in laptop?

Comment: Why can't you update the software?  You can use Xcode 12 on Catalina and your hardware can run Big Sur.  You can't downgrade an iOS device.  You can try this https://medium.com/better-programming/debugging-on-ios-14-with-xcode-11-d332f12f49dd but an Xcode upgrade would definitely be the better approach

Comment: @Paulw11 Reason one - Hard disk space issues. I have XCode , Android and Flutter SDK installed, together with MS office and outlook. It had consumed all the space.

Comment: @Paulw11 Reason two - I'm in a middle of a delivery, not willing to messup things because of an update and make delays. Currently I'm using Simulators and TestFlight to test apps because of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please download the 14.2 OS support file from [here](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport) and drop it in the /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/